# Convert installscript to Basic MSI

Tags: windows-installer, installscript, installshield-2010, basic-msi

Is there a way to convert InstallScript to Basic MSI in installshield 2010?

Comment: See my answer at the bottom for an alternative to the accepted solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield16helplib_sp1/ProjectConverters.htm) from Flexara, their Repackager product can convert from pure InstallScript to Basic MSI.  Repackager is only available in InstallShield Premier edition or AdminStudio.

I have never used the product myself, so I cannot vouch for its effectiveness.

Answer (score 2):

Installscript Projects can be classified as LEGACY installation technique.
The Basic MSI is the standard way of installing apps on Windows machines.

The Installscript Engine is responsible for handling the installation logic. This is very similar to the old SCRIPT-BASED installs which were the only way to install apps prior to 2000.

The Windows Installer Engine(or Service), takes care of the installation logic. It reads MSI database and performs steps accordingly. Thus, Basic MSI is a TRANSACTIONAL installation procedure.

There is no ONE-TO-ONE mapping available for Installscript and Basic MSI projects.
Repackaging is the only way out if writing a Basic MSI from scratch is not an option.

Comment: Installscript MSI is indeed a deprecated project type from Installshield. It is not recommended for any project type.

Answer (score 0):

Installscript can be captured by Wise Package Studio by doing a prescan and then a post scan. Basically you do a prescan of your system, which scans the registry, files, versions, odbc's, etc. Then you install you software, and do the post scan which does the same as the prescan. This method compares the two to see what changes you have to your system.

Another method is to launch the program at get to the first prompt, then click Start > Run > %TEMP% then click ok. Monitor that directory for any deposited .msi files.

If you get a .msi you can use in the command prompt "Msiexec.exe /i nameOfFile.msi /qb" to silently install.

I am assuming your a systems admin. Your question is great, hope I was able to add my 2 cents and contribute.

**Notable Software:** 
Wise Package Studio.
AutoIT.
SMS Installer (In worse case situations)

Answer (score 0):

I found [**this article**](http://shieldmaster.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/converting-a-msi-to-an-installshield-basic-project/), it should show you how you can relatively quickly convert your Installscript MSI project to Basic MSI by opening either the Installscript MSI or a compiled MSI in "**Wizard mode**" from the "Open Project Dialog".

I haven't tested it, but it should do the job. I am not sure if it will properly convert everything, but it is probably good enough so you can clean up the rest manually.